# Distortion / perspective correction on live video

Tags: video

I am recording and streaming live from lecture halls, and I need to correct perspective to ensure that large blackboards are not distorted/skewed. As we are streaming multiple lectures simultaneously using automated systems, we cannot have a computer hooked up.
So I am looking for a hardware based solution that perform the the same as [mimoLive’s “Deskew Filter”](https://mimolive.com/mimolive-2-8-deskew-filter/).

[image: mimoLive]

Searching the internet I have only found one solution ([AlphaEye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5t_JK3sCXYE)) for this, but the company does not exist anymore.
The video feed is an SDI signal, but a solution for HDMI or RTSP would also work.

If anyone knows of such a device, I would really appreciate a link.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By far the cheapest solution will be to put a computer in the chain.

If you can stream the video using [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), there is [a 3D transform plugin](https://github.com/xaymar/obs-streamfx/wiki/Filter-3D-Transform) that can  transform/corner pin a video to adjust the perspective.
I haven't used it though.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I would prefer to have the correction done in a hardware component. I am looking for a very stable solution that can run 24/7/365 and where I don’t have the hassle of OS-updates.